# redux reducer not receiving an action

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

good day everyone,
today is my first go at redux and I followed a youtube tutorial to get my boilerplate setup to use redux with react-native, and obviously, I'm facing some problem and can't see the mistakes I might have made since the concept still a bit fuzzy for me.

so I created a reduced, an action and a type to use as a starting point. the problem is after connecting the state to the component, and triggering the action in the component's constructor I get a result from the action (tested it with a console log) but the state is not changed.

well this is my code:

**store**

```
import {
    createStore,
    applyMiddleware
} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './src/reducers/rootReducer';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(...middleware));

export default store;
```

**root reducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import companyReducer from './companyReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    companies: companyReducer
});
```

**company reducer**

```
import { FETCH_COMPANIES } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    values: []
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_COMPANIES: return {
            ...state,
            values: action.payload
        };
        default: return {
            test: 'testing'
        };
    }
}
```

**company action**

```
import {
    FETCH_COMPANIES
} from './types';

export const fetchCompanies = () => dispatch => 
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_COMPANIES,
        payload: [{
                id: 1,
                text: "CHRONUS FRANCE .A."
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                text: "two"
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                text: "three"
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                text: "four"
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                text: "five"
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                text: "six"
            },
            {
                id: 7,
                text: "seven"
            },
            {
                id: 8,
                text: "eight"
            },
            {
                id: 9,
                text: "nine"
            },
            {
                id: 10,
                text: "ten"
            },
        ]
    });
```

**types**

```
export const FETCH_COMPANIES = 'FETCH_COMPANIES';
```

**the component**

```
//imports
import {
  connect
} from 'react-redux';
import { fetchCompanies } from '../../actions/companyActions';

//constructor
class Welcome extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    props.fetchCompanies();
    console.log(props);
  }
}

//map to props and connect
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  companies: state.companies
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCompanies })(Welcome);
```

this is what i got on the console after logging the props:

> {…}
>
> companies: {…}
>
> ```
>  test: "testing"
>  <prototype>: Object { … }
> ```
>
> fetchCompanies: "function () {\n      return dispatch(actionCreator.apply(this, arguments));\n    }"
>
> navigation: Object { pop: "function () {\n        var actionCreator = actionCreators[actionName];\n        var action = actionCreator.apply(void 0, arguments);\n        return navigation.dispatch(action);\n      }", popToTop: "function () {\n        var actionCreator = actionCreators[actionName];\n        var action = actionCreator.apply(void 0, arguments);\n        return navigation.dispatch(action);\n      }", push: "function () {\n        var actionCreator = actionCreators[actionName];\n        var action = actionCreator.apply(void 0, arguments);\n        return navigation.dispatch(action);\n      }", … }
>
> screenProps: undefined
>
> : Object { … }
> 305278fb-9c91-40bc-b0b1-9fa113a58b1f:93248:15

i hope someone here finds what is not working and what i missed and help me out with this.
thanks in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: in `the component` you are not importing React. is this a mistake? `import {Component} from 'react'`

Comment: no all the import are there i just didn't include them. the component already works and fully tested. the problem is with redux

Comment: @chawkichalladia please try my answer.

Comment: What do you mean by `result from the action (tested it with a console log)`? Could you please add the logs to your question?

Comment: i just added a console log inside my action then called the action inside my constructor with this.props and saw the log. it was a regular string nothing special about just for me to see if it works or not.

Comment: I think you might want to log like `console.log(props.fetchCompanies())`.

Comment: ok i'll comment the log under your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check whether the store has updated or not by logging the props inside `render`. Any change in props cannot be observed in your constructor.

`props.fetchCompanies()` is calling a function which returns a function. This function is to be passed to dispatch after which it is intercepted by `redux-thunk`.

`props.fetchCompanies()` will just call the outer function, but not the inner. The inner function requires an argument(`dispatch`), which is provided by redux-thunk.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
      fetchCompanies: () => dispatch(fetchCompanies())
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Welcome);
```

**NOTE**

You do not have to add dispatch manually as shown above, as `connect` automatically dispatches the fields in the returned object.

Comment: thanks for the help but this didn't change anything.

Comment: {…} payload: (10) […]
​​0: Object { id: 1, text: "CHRONUS FRANCE .A." }​​
1: Object { id: 2, text: "two" }​​
2: Object { id: 3, text: "three" }​​
3: Object { id: 4, text: "four" }​​
4: Object { id: 5, text: "five" }​​
5: Object { id: 6, text: "six" }​​
6: Object { id: 7, text: "seven" }​​
7: Object { id: 8, text: "eight" }​​
8: Object { id: 9, text: "nine" }​​
9: Object { id: 10, text: "ten" }​​
length: 10​​
<prototype>: Array []​
type: "FETCH_COMPANIES"​
<prototype>: Object { … }
4ac3dd6f-ba7d-437f-b45c-1e4b42a78146:93250:15

Comment: this is the log. the action works and the results are available just not added to state

Comment: The function will be called, but for the inner function to be called it has to be dispatched.

Comment: i tried the suggestion given in this post but none of them worked so far. i even copied that code from a tutorial where it works

Comment: Have you installed `redux-thunk`?

Comment: Is it possible to mention the link to the tutorial?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191730/discussion-between-10101010-and-chawki-challadia).

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if your actionTypes are imported correctly?

EDIT:
I checked in your reducer default case is called first before case FETCH_COMPANIES. Not sure why this is called but that way your state is overwritten with test property. There is no more values property. Then fetchCompanies is called in your constructor. It adds values to your state. There is state.companies in your mapStateToProps but you don't have such a property in your state. Try

`values: state.values` and you will see your companies

Comment: yes i tested it by returning the type in default case in my switch statement

Comment: no actually redux was working fine i was just not clear on how it works so i missed few points. thanks for help though

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest minor changes to actions.

```
import {
    FETCH_COMPANIES
} from './types';

export const fetchCompanies = payload => ({type: FETCH_COMPANIES, payload})
```

update the component like

```
    import {
      connect
    } from 'react-redux';
    import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
    import { fetchCompanies } from '../../actions/companyActions';

    const payload = [{
            id: 1,
            text: "CHRONUS FRANCE .A."
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            text: "two"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            text: "three"
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            text: "four"
        }]

    //constructor
    class Welcome extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        props.fetchCompanies(payload);
        console.log(props);
      }
    }

    //map to props and connect
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      companies: state.companies
    });

   const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({fetchCompanies}, dispatch)


    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Welcome);
```

Comment: in the actions i tried `fetchCompanies()` and it gave me and error `dispatch not a function`. also tried `fetchCompanies` and `() => fetchCompanies()` and nothing changed for my initial problem in both situations

Comment: @chawkichalladia I just updated the answer with suggesting minor changes

Comment: so you suggest that i do the actions outside the actions then pass the results ? i'm new to redux but this seems to be opposing to what i read about redux. can you please explain further how would this work in the future if you don't mind. i'm kinda confused now

Comment: in company action return the payload. `export const fetchCompanies = () => dispatch => 
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_COMPANIES,
        payload: [{,,, `   change to =>  `export const fetchCompanies = () => dispatch => 
    dispatch( return {
        type: FETCH_COMPANIES,
        payload: [{`

Comment: i'm already returning a payload. and for testing redux i'm returning a static payload

Comment: sure. The action that you created is when dispatched it will send same payload. so I made the changed to accept payload from component who is going to dispatch it. Also I am using the dispatch provided by redux in component rather to use in action creator as you have used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put FETCH_COMPANIES in quotes in your switch statement in the reducer eg. "FETCH_COMPANIES" so that the case is recognized and the reducer doesn't just return the default.